# How to prove that $(\sec x-\cos x)(\csc x -\sin x)=\tan x/(1+\tan^2x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I've tried solving from both sides but can't seem to get them equal. Any tips on which side to start on and what to do after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline**: $$\sec x - \cos x = \frac 1 {\cos{x}} - \cos x = \frac{1 - \cos^2 x}{\cos x} = \frac {\sin^2 x}{\cos{x}}$$

Likewise, $$\csc x - \sin x = \frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin x}$$

Now divide and simplify, noting that

$$1 + \tan^2 x = \sec^2 x = \frac 1 {\cos^2{x}}$$

Combine this with the fact that $\tan x = \sin x / \cos x$.

Comment: Got it now thanks. Had to develop both sides.